# How can I create the table with borders only at the bottom for specific columns?

Tags: html, css

I have an html page where I need to create section containing the following content:

[image]

I have the following css:

```
#tblComments > tbody >first-of-type > tr > td:first-child 
{
  border-bottom:1px solid black;         
}
```

and the following html:

```
<div id="comments">
    <table id="tblComments">
        <tr>
            <td>ISSUER COMMENTS (IF APPROPRIATE)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

How can I create that?

Comment: look at the edit. thx

Comment: `>first-of-type` isn't valid

Comment: But how can I correct it?

Comment: Your title says "specific columns" but which columns, or cells should have the styling applied?

Comment: I need to have a bottom border for all the columns except one with the text

Answer (score 0):

give the column you want to have a bottom border this class

```
<div class="border"></div>
```

then in css do this

```
.border {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose where you want to use the borders with a class selector

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .border {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black ;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%;">
          <tr>
            <td class="border">Jill</td>
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td> 
            <td>94</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: But your code example isn't using a class selector. You put a border around the table and each cell.

Comment: I change the code, I hope i can help you. in that way you can add the class when you want the border